# When passing a class as a parameter of a function, can a property of that class be marked as required during build time?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I want to be able to set a class as a parameter of a method, like this:

```
public DoThing(MyClass class)
{
    //TODO: do thing
}
```

But I also want some of the properties of the class to be required. I can check those properties and throw an error or something during runtime, but I was wondering if it were possible to declare some of those properties required during build time.

I can always list out the parameters, but I like using classes to make the code easier to read. Is this possible or do I just have to do runtime checks?

---

To clarify, I wanted to make something like this, less ambiguous:

```
DoThing(true, true, null, true);
```

At a glance, I can't see what those properties are. So normally I'd make it a class and set the values like this:

```
var myClass = new MyClass() 
{
    IsDone = true,
    IsNotDone = null,
    CouldItBeDone = false,
    IfNotDone = true
};

DoThing(myClass);
```

As I'm reading the code, I can easily see the name of the properties and that gives me an idea of what I'm looking at. But if `IsNotDone` cannot be null, there's no way I know of to check that during build time. I'd have to do a null check during runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by a property being required? The property's *existence* is just a matter of it being declared in the class. Do you mean "the property's value is non-null"? It would really help if you could explain what you're looking for more clearly.

Comment: You should probably have a look at some best practices defined in the programming guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Comment: And remember, what is easier to read for you doesn't make it so for someone else.

Comment: You can make the `MyClass` constructor take the required properties as constructor parameters. That way, it's impossible to create a `MyClass` without those properties being initialized.

Comment: @JonSkeet if someone were to call DoThing() without MyClass, VS would complain that there isn't a method with that name that doesn't take any parameters. I want the same thing during build time, except for designated properties of the class.

Comment: @RaymondChen right. But I'm back to the readability issue. It's not a big deal when there are 2 parameters. But becomes a problem as the parameter count increases. It's not the end of the world, just something nice to have so I don't have to hover over a method when I see, DoSomething(true, true, false, true, false), etc.

Comment: Make `MyClass` such that it's impossible to construct it without specifying these properties. Or make some sort of `MyClassWrapper` (stand-alone or inheriting from `MyClass`) that is impossible to construct without specifying these properties, and make your method accept that instead. In either case it will all happen at runtime, you just move the parameter checking from `DoThing` into `MyClassWrapper`.

Comment: What do you mean by "except for designated properties of the class"? There's nothing a caller can do to change what properties `MyClass` has. It can change which ones have non-default values, but that's not the same thing - and that's what I was trying to ask about in the first comment. I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Maybe if you could show an example of what should be valid or what should be invalid it would be clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added an example to the question. I just want the runtime to be able to check if a property in the class should be required when the code is being built. Like how see it when we call a method without a property. My example isn't perfect, but I hope it clarifies things.

Comment: Right - again, it's not the presence of the property, it's whether or not it has a particular value, or whether that value has been specified as part of construction. (I don't know what you mean by "when we call a method without a property"). As GSerg said, you should basically make it impossible to create the instance of `MyClass` without specifying everything that's needed for it.

Comment: @JonSkeet that brings me back to the ambiguity though. If I were to call, `DoThing()` with no parameters, VS would complain that it had no parameters, right? I'm trying to see if I could do the same thing, but with the properties inside of the class. So I can see at build time, if the value is null or not. If I pass these as parameters to the constructors, I'm back to not knowing what they are at a glance. I didn't expect this to be possible. But I wanted to double check before I wrote it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you are trying to do will be solved neatly by [named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), without the use of a helper class.

Just call your function like this, giving explicit argument names:

```cs
DoThing(quickly: true, silently: true, why: null, verbose: true);
```

You can pass named arguments in any order.

Comment: That's as probably as close as I'll get. Thanks